# Creating custom CLRegions for monitoring

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, geofencing, clregion

I'm building an app that uses geofencing but I realised that CLRegion has many limitations, for example:

- that location authorizationStatus must be .authorizedAlways in order for region monitoring to work.
- only circular regions can be monitored

This limits the functionality that can be applied using region monitoring. However after doing some research i found out that there are ways to change this behaviour by creating a custom class of CLRegion.

To be honest I have no idea how to do this or where to start. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how such a custom CLRegion class could allow customised geo-fencing?

There is a tutorial on appcoda that talked about this briefly, but it wasn't in depth at all, you can find it here:

https://www.appcoda.com/geo-targeting-ios/

There they suggest starting with protocols such as:

```
protocol RegionProtocol {
   var coordinate: CLLocation {get}
   var radius: CLLocationDistance {get}
   var identifier: String {get}

   func updateRegion()
}

protocol RegionDelegateProtocol {
   func didEnterRegion()
   func didExitRegion()
}
```

And from these one can create custom functionality for CLRegions, such as monitoring polygons etc.

How should one get started on implementing custom regions?

Thanks!